# Having trouble in setting up conditions for action groups in XPages button events

Tags: action, conditional-statements, xpages

I have this button on my custom control which I want to use to enable the users of the application to save the current contents as draft. The challenge is that I have 5 data-sources connected to different back-end forms and all reside on a single X-pages in different tabs and these tabs are shown and/or hidden based on the document work flow conditions. I need to be able to provide the save facility for all the data sources but need to set a field before that. To achieve this I used the Action Groups in the button and tried to execute them based on certain conditions, but they don't seem to execute at all even when the conditions are true. Here is the action group code:

```xml
<xp:this.action>
    <xp:actionGroup>
        <xp:actionGroup>
            <xp:this.condition><![CDATA[#{javascript:if(parseInt(viewScope.curApprCycle) > 2){
                if(parseInt(viewScope.curApprStatus) < 2){return true;} else return false;}else  return false;}]]></xp:this.condition>
            <xp:saveDocument
                var="introspectionSheet"></xp:saveDocument>
        </xp:actionGroup>
        <xp:actionGroup>
            <xp:this.condition><![CDATA[#{javascript:if(parseInt(viewScope.curApprCycle)>2){
                return viewScope.showTLPTab;}return false;}]]></xp:this.condition>
            <xp:saveDocument
                var="TLP"></xp:saveDocument>
        </xp:actionGroup>
        <xp:actionGroup>
            <xp:this.condition><![CDATA[#{javascript:if(parseInt(viewScope.curApprCycle)>2){
                return viewScope.showAttributesTab;}return false;}]]></xp:this.condition>
            <xp:saveDocument
                var="Attributes"></xp:saveDocument>
        </xp:actionGroup>
        <xp:actionGroup>
            <xp:this.condition><![CDATA[#{javascript:if(parseInt(viewScope.curApprCycle) > 2){
                if(parseInt(viewScope.curApprStatus) > 1){
                    return true;
                }
                return false;}return false;}]]></xp:this.condition>
            <xp:saveDocument
                var="PenPicture"></xp:saveDocument>
        </xp:actionGroup>
    </xp:actionGroup>
</xp:this.action>
```

Comment: Finally got what the issue was. I was trying to reference a data-source that was declared in a child dojo tab-container from the parent container and it seems that does not work (i discoverd that today).

Comment: Write it to answer and tag your question as answered, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got what the issue was. I was trying to reference a data-source that was declared in a child dojo tab-container from the parent container and it seems that does not work (i discoverd that today).